# Support for creating table out of limited number of column in Presto

Tags: hive, presto

I was playing around with Presto. I uploaded parquet file with 10 columns.I want to created table (external location s3) in meta store with 5 column using presto-cli. Looks like presto doesn't support this ?
Is there any other way to get this working.

Comment: Did you try `hive.parquet.use-column-names=true` in hive.properties?

Answer (score 0):

That should be easily possible if you are using Parquet or ORC file formats. This is another advantage of keeping metadata separate than actual data. As mentioned in the comments, you should use column names to access the fields instead of index.

One of the example:

```
CREATE TABLE hive.web.request_logs (
  request_time timestamp,
  url varchar,
  ip varchar,
  user_agent varchar
)
WITH (
  format = 'parquet',
  external_location = 's3://my-bucket/data/logs/'
)
```

Reference:

https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#examples